# Delete the canvas in Pysimplegui

Tags: python, matplotlib, pysimplegui

I'm new to programming, and I tried to find the solution to related questions here, but it get me nowhere and I'm starting to bang the walls with my head now.

The problem is the following: I need to create a program with GUI for a university project. The idea is that I take data from big datasets, then a user can input a country name, and data for the selected countries will form a plot. I have 2 plots with different data I want to use, and I have 2 separate buttons for each type:

````
```
    #function that graphs the first plot
def vaccine_cases_plot(vaccine_list, cases_list):
plt.scatter(
    y = vaccine_list,
    x = cases_list)
plt.ylabel("Percentage of fully vaccinated people")
plt.xlabel("Number of new cases per Million as of 01.12.2021")
plt.ioff()
return plt.gcf()

   #function that graphs the second plot
def vaccine_gdp_plot(vaccine_list, gdp_list):
plt.scatter(
    y = vaccine_list,
    x = gdp_list)
plt.ylabel("Percentage of fully vaccinated people")
plt.xlabel("GDP per capita in 2019(USD)")
plt.ioff()
return plt.gcf()

    #helper function to display plot on canvas   
    plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(left=0.15)
    matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
    def draw_figure(canvas, figure):
       figure_canvas_agg = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, canvas)
       figure_canvas_agg.get_tk_widget().pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=1)
       figure_canvas_agg.draw()
       return figure_canvas_agg

   #empty lists where data for countries, selected by user, will be stored 
   vaccines_to_plot = []
   cases_to_plot = []
   gdp_to_plot = []


    #pysimplegui interface layout
    interface_column = [
[
    sg.Text("Select a countries you would like to see on the graph:", font=("Arial", 14))
],
[
    sg.In(size =(25, 1), enable_events=True, key="country_selected"),
    sg.Button("Add country")
],
[
    sg.Text("Selected countries are: ", size=(20,10), font=("Arial", 14), key = "selected_countries")
],
[
    sg.Button("Clear selection", key = "clear")
],
[
    sg.Button("GDP vs. Vaccination rate", key = "gdp_vaccine"),
    sg.Button("Vaccination vs. new cases per day", key = "vaccine_cases")
   
],
[
    sg.Text(font=("Arial", 12), key="warning_message")
]
     ]

   graph_column = [
[sg.Canvas(size=(500,500), key="canvas")]

]

layout = [
[
    sg.Column(interface_column),
    sg.VSeperator(),
    sg.Column(graph_column),
]
]
window = sg.Window("Vaxxi-nation", layout, margins=(50, 50), finalize=True)
canv = window["canvas"].TKCanvas

#main loop
while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

#User inputs name of the country, respective data goes to the lists, name of the country is 
 displayed
    if event == "Add country":
        selected_country = values["country_selected"]
    if selected_country in new_cases_per_m and selected_country in fully_vaccinated and 
  selected_country in countries_gdp:
        try:
            vaccines_to_plot.append(float(fully_vaccinated[selected_country]))
            cases_to_plot.append(float(new_cases_per_m[selected_country]))
            gdp_to_plot.append(round(float(countries_gdp[selected_country]), 2))
            display = window["selected_countries"]
            display.update(display.get() + selected_country + '\n')
        except:
            window["warning_message"].update("One of the datasets doesn't have data for this country")
    else:
        window["warning_message"].update("One of the datasets doesn't have data for this country")

#Button to graph the first plot
    if event == "gdp_vaccine":
        draw_figure(canv, vaccine_gdp_plot(vaccines_to_plot, gdp_to_plot))
#button to graph the second plot
    if event == "vaccine_cases":
        draw_figure(canv, vaccine_cases_plot(vaccines_to_plot, cases_to_plot))
    if event == "clear":
        display.update('')
        vaccines_to_plot = []
        cases_to_plot = []
        gdp_to_plot = []
        
event, values = window.read()      
window.close()
```
````

Now, when I press one of the buttons for the first time, the plot displays on canvas just as I want it to be. But if I'd like to display the other plot, instead of being rewritten over the previous one, it creates a new plot, replaces the old one with it, and makes a copy of a new plot on the right.

What I want to have, is when a new button is pressed (or the old one is pressed again) the new plot should replace the old one. I looked up for many ways to do that, but I have a feeling that there should be something simple and obvious that I fail to see here. The last thing I tried and gave up after was to delete the canvas each time the button is pressed and then draw it anew. I tried to do it like this:

```
#first button is clicked
    if event == "gdp_vaccine":
        canv.TKCanvas.delete("all")
        draw_figure(canv, vaccine_gdp_plot(vaccines_to_plot, gdp_to_plot))
```

But it literally did nothing (although no error was thrown). I will really appreciate any help here since I've been struggling with it for the whole day already and there's no way this thing should be that complicated.

Comment: The PySimpleGUI GitHub Issues are an excellent place to ask questions rather than banging your head.  "Don't suffer in silence" as the documentation says.  Thankfully, Jason comes here as well as is manning the Issues on GitHub.  Over time, Matplotlib implementations moved away from Canvas and on to Image and Graph elements.  There are 16 demo programs showing various ways of integrating PySimpleGUI with Matplotlib.  Usually, the newer the demo, the better as the project evolves, learns.

Answer (score 0):

Following code just to delete all items in `sg.Canvas`, not canvas of matplotlib figure in `sg.Canvas`.

```py
canv.TKCanvas.delete("all")
```

It is not easy to read your long and incomplete code.

Here's my code to demo two graphs and redraw again and again, maybe it can help you.

```py
import math

from matplotlib import use as use_agg
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def pack_figure(graph, figure):
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, graph.Widget)
    plot_widget = canvas.get_tk_widget()
    plot_widget.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)
    return plot_widget

def plot_figure(index, theta):
    fig = plt.figure(index)         # Active an existing figure
    ax = plt.gca()                  # Get the current axes
    x = [degree for degree in range(1080)]
    y = [math.sin((degree+theta)/180*math.pi) for degree in range(1080)]
    ax.cla()                        # Clear the current axes
    ax.set_title(f"Sensor Data {index}")
    ax.set_xlabel("X axis")
    ax.set_ylabel("Y axis")
    ax.set_xscale('log')
    ax.grid()
    plt.plot(x, y)                  # Plot y versus x as lines and/or markers
    fig.canvas.draw()               # Rendor figure into canvas

# Use Tkinter Agg
use_agg('TkAgg')

layout = [[sg.Graph((640, 480), (0, 0), (640, 480), key='Graph1'), sg.Graph((640, 480), (0, 0), (640, 480), key='Graph2')]]
window = sg.Window('Matplotlib', layout, finalize=True)


# Initial
graph1 = window['Graph1']
graph2 = window['Graph2']
plt.ioff()                          # Turn the interactive mode off
fig1 = plt.figure(1)                # Create a new figure
ax1 = plt.subplot(111)              # Add a subplot to the current figure.
fig2 = plt.figure(2)                # Create a new figure
ax2 = plt.subplot(111)              # Add a subplot to the current figure.
pack_figure(graph1, fig1)           # Pack figure under graph
pack_figure(graph2, fig2)
theta1 = 0                          # theta for fig1
theta2 = 90                         # theta for fig2
plot_figure(1, theta1)
plot_figure(2, theta2)

while True:

    event, values = window.read(timeout=10)

    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == sg.TIMEOUT_EVENT:
        theta1 = (theta1 + 40) % 360
        plot_figure(1, theta1)
        theta2 = (theta2 + 40) % 260
        plot_figure(2, theta2)

window.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience with the code - I'll try to make it cleaner.
I changed my plotting display to sg.Graph instead of sg.Canvas, and followed the example you provided - and it works. Thank you very much! Sorry again for formulating an already dumb question even dumber - my brain was melting, and now it is saved, so I guess, again, many thanks to you!